# Hi. I wrote a program and after re-running it on the simulator, it now shows the home screen in black

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios-simulator

I wrote a program and after re-running it on the simulator, it now shows the home screen in black.

[image]

Comment: What the console says, the SceneDelegate class is missing. Did you throw it away? . You might find it in the trash or you can create a new project to copy the SceneDelegate.swift file from there.

Comment: We really do not need to see a picture of a black screen. We know what it looks like. Also, when you get relevant console messages, they are text: copy and paste them as formatted text into your question.

Comment: Sure. Thank you for guiding me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have tried to adapt your project not to use scene delegates, but you did it wrong. Here are the things you need to do:

1. Make sure the *Info.plist* has no Application Scene Manifest entry.
2. Make sure the AppDelegate has no methods that mention scenes.
3. Make sure the AppDelegate has a `window` property.

Comment: Thanks.  This solved my problem